# Fortran program won't add into library archive

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran library archive (libmy.a) that contains various subroutines.
I then try to add another one with:

ifort -c -O3 ~/mydir/sub.f

ar -rv ~/mydir/libmy.a sub.o

However, while libmy's attributes change, its size does not, so it seems as if sub is not being incorporated (and trying to use the library gives an error message "undefined reference to `sub_'".

The other subroutines in the library were added exactly like this, without any problems.

What reasons could there be for this particular subroutine not being incorporated?